# Libgdx android force closing

Tags: android, 3d, libgdx

I want to create a 3d android game using libgdx which I just started....I followed xoppa's blog exactly on using asset manager to lad models......it worked but when I tried to get the camera to look at centre of the model using this code:

```
BoundingBox bound;
.....
public vector3 InstanceCentre(ModelInstance instance)
{
     Vector3 centre;
     instance.calculateBoundingBox(bounds);
     centre=bounds.getCentre;
     return centre;
}
public void render()
{
     cam.lookAt(instanceCentre(instance));
     .....
 }
 .......
```

it force closes when I tried this so I changed it back to the original without the instanceCentre method and other things but it still force closes when I tested the reverted version on another phone it works...but no matter what I try on the first phone it doesn't work

Comment: Check the logcat! There should be a stacktrace.

Comment: I'll add the logcat report now

Comment: Or instead how can I get error from the logcat

Comment: see http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html